# Let $X \sim \exp(\lambda)$. Find the Moment generating function of $Y=1+\ln(X)$.

Tags: integration, moment-generating-functions

Let $X \sim \exp(\lambda)$. Find the Moment generating function of $Y=1+\ln(X)$.

I tried this but got myself stuck in an infinite descent of Integration by Parts. This makes me think there is an easier method.

$$m_Y(t) = E[e^{t(1+\ln(x)}] = \int_0^\infty e^{t(1+\ln(x)} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx = \lambda e^{t} \int_0^\infty x^te^{-\lambda x} dx$$
The issue is that when integrating by parts I try to reduce $x^t$ and then $x^{t-1}$, and I do not see a stopping point.

Comment: Are you familiar with Gamma function? The last integral converges for $t>-1$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom if only I could remove the $\lambda$ from the last integral it would match perfectly with the gamma function

Comment: @JacFrall then what about a change of variable?

Comment: @Jac Frall Perform the change of integration variables from $x$ to $z$ via $z=\lambda x$.

Comment: @Masacroso Yup, didnt see it at first. Multiplying inside by $\lambda ^t$ works

Comment: @Gary side note.. What about the lower bound of 0. ln(0) is undefined. Does that mean we need to change the domain in which we integrate?

Comment: @Jac Frall What you have done so far is correct. The point $0$ has Lebesgue measure $0$, so you do not have to worry about "$\log 0$". The final integral converges if $t>-1$. When you perform $z=\lambda x$ the integration limits will not change.

Comment: If you have solved the problem, you can answer the question and accept it.